# how to use same popup jquery for two div

Tags: javascript, css, html, popup

how to use same popup jquery for two div. i have a jquery for the popup and it is div popup and  i want to use the same jquery for another div. please help. the code is given below

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<style>
#backgroundPopup {
z-index:1;
position: fixed;
display:none;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background:#000000;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
#toPopup {
font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border: 10px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
color: #333333;
display: none;
font-size: 14px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -402px;
position: fixed;
top: 20%;
width: 800px;
z-index: 2;
}
div.loader {
background: url("../img/loading.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
height: 32px;
width: 32px;
display: none;
z-index: 9999;
top: 40%;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
margin-left: -10px;
}
div.close {
background: url("../img/closebox.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
cursor: pointer;
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
right: -27px;
top: -24px;
width: 30px;
}
span.ecs_tooltip {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: none;
font-size: 11px;
height: 16px;
opacity: 0.7;
padding: 4px 3px 2px 5px;
position: absolute;
right: -62px;
text-align: center;
top: -51px;
width: 93px;
}
span.arrow {
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-top: 7px solid #000000;
display: block;
height: 1px;
left: 40px;
position: relative;
top: 3px;
width: 1px;
}
div#popup_content {
margin: 4px 7px;
/* remove this comment if you want scroll bar
overflow-y:scroll;
height:200px
*/
}</style> 
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="topopup"><div id="ack" class="topopup">Location</div></a>

<div id="toPopup">

    <div class="close"></div>
    <span class="ecs_tooltip">Press Esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
    <div id="popup_content" width="400px" height="500px"> 

 <input type="text" name="mm" id="id">
       <button id="ok">ok</button>
    </div> <!--your content end-->

</div> <!--toPopup end-->

<div class="loader"></div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
</body>
```

---

jquery for popup. i want use this jquery for another div. but i given the same name for another div but i when click that link it displays previous div

```
jQuery(function($) {

$("a.topopup").click(function() {
        loading(); // loading
        setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
            loadPopup(); // function show popup
        }, 500); // .5 second
return false;
});

/* event for close the popup */
$("div.close").hover(
                function() {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').show();
                },
                function () {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').hide();
                }
            );

$("div.close").click(function() {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});

$(this).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    }
});

    $("div#backgroundPopup").click(function() {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});
$("button#ok").click(function() {
    disablePopup(); 
 });
$('a.livebox').click(function() {
    alert('Hello World!');
return false;
});

 /************** start: functions. **************/
function loading() {
    $("div.loader").show();
}
function closeloading() {
    $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');
}

var popupStatus = 0; // set value

function loadPopup() {
    if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
        closeloading(); // fadeout loading
        $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
        $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7");
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001);
        popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
    }
}

function disablePopup() {
    if(popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup
        $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");
        popupStatus = 0;  // and set value to 0
    }
}
/************** end: functions. **************/
    }); // jQuery End
```

---

i want use this jquery for another div. but i given the same name for another div but i when click that link it displays previous div

Answer (score 0):

you never used a `<a class="topopup1"></a>`?

Comment: sorry that was my mistake. i corrected that problem. the actual problem is, i want to use this jquery for another div also . please help me.....

Answer (score 0):

My suggestiong is that a target attribute can be added to `<a>` to imply which div will be poped up.

for example:

html code

```
<a class="popup-button" target="#p1"></a>
<a class="popup-button" target="#p2"></a>
<div class="toPopup" id="p1">...</div>
<div class="toPopup" id="p2">...</div>
```

js code

```
$(".popup-button").click(function{
    loading($(this).attr("target")); // loading
    setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
        loadPopup($(this).attr("target")); // function show popup
    }, 500); // .5 second
});

function loading(selector) {
    $(selector).show();
}
function loadPopup(selector) {
    if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
        closeloading(); // fadeout loading
        $(selector).fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
        popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class name with your anchor tags

```
<a class='topopup1'>Show Popup</a>
```